# Spanning $\mathbb{I}$ in $V$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have the following definition,

**Definition** If $\rho$ : $G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation we call $v \in V$ $G$-invariant if 
$$g \cdot v =v \ \ \forall g \in G $$

Then I have the statement If $v \neq 0$ is invariant, it spans a copy of $\mathbb{I}$ (trivial representation) in $V$.

I do not understand what it means that "it spans a copy of  $\mathbb{I}$ in $V$. This does feel intuitively correct to me but I am trying to think about it concretely with definitions.

Comment: So what's your question? The statement seems obvious.

Comment: Well $v$ spans a $1$-dimensional submodule of $V$. It would be more accurate to say that $v$ spans a copy of the module afforded by ${\mathbb I}$, because the trivial representation ${\mathbb I}$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to ${\rm GL}(W)$, where $w$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space with $g\cdot w=w$ for all $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be the field you're working over.

If $g\cdot v = v$ for all $g \in G$ then the span of $v$, i.e. the line $kv$, is a subrepresentation $\rho'\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(kv)$ of $V$.  This representation is isomorphic to the trivial representation $\mathbb I\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(k)$.  That means there is a linear map $f\colon k \to kv$ such that for all $g \in G$ and $a \in k$ we have $f(\mathbb I(g)a) = \rho'(g)f(a)$.  In this case you can define $f$ by $a \mapsto av$.

Comment: Where does this come from? $f(\mathbb I(g)a) = \rho'(g)f(a)$

Comment: The definition of a homomorphism of representations.